# Why categories are not displayed?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

categories.blade.php

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)

  <option value="{{ $category->id ?? '' }}" 
    @isset($article->id)
     @foreach($article->categories as $category_article) -->
      @if($category->id ==  $category_article->id)
        selected="selected"
      @endif
     @endforeach 
    @endisset



 {!! $delimiter ?? '' !!}{{ $category->title ?? '' }}

  </option>

  @if (isset($category->children) && is_array($category->children) && count($category->children) > 0)

      @include('admin.articles.partials.categories', [
        'categories' => $category->children,
        'delimiter'  => ' - ' . $delimiter,

      ])

  @endif
@endforeach
```

form.blade.php

```
<select id="parent_id" class="form-control" name="categories[]" multiple="">
  @include('admin.articles.partials.categories',
          ['categories' => $categories])

</select>
```

This is my categoryController 
categorycontroller.php

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.categories.index',[
            'categories' => category::paginate(10)
        ]);
    }


public function create()
{
    return view('admin.categories.create', [
       'category'   => null,
       'categories' => category::with('children')->where('parent_id', '0')->get(),
       'delimiter'  => ''
    ]);
}


    public function store(Request $request)
{
   category::create($request->all());
   return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
}

    public function edit(Category $category)
   {
    return view('admin.categories.edit', [
       'category'   => $category,
       'categories' => category::with('children')->where('parent_id', '0')->get(),
       'delimiter'  => ''
    ]);
}




}
```

This is my articleController 
articlecontroller.php

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.articles.index',[
            'articles' => Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10)
        ]);
    }


    public function create()
    {   
        return view('admin.articles.create',[
            'article' => null,
            'categories' => Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get(),
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::create($request->all());

        if($request->input('categories'))  :
            $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
        endif;
        return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');    
    }

    public function edit(Article $article)
    {
       return view('admin.articles.edit',[
         'article' => $article,
              'categories' => Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get(),
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
   }

}
```

why categories are not displayed in select? Just started to study Laravel and a little misunderstood. I really hope for your help. I set the code above. Please help me. It’s impossible to display categories in select

Comment: Can you share the code on controller..??

Comment: I share controller. Please help me

Comment: What is category::paginate(10). category is a model object.???